Why validation loss is decreasing but accuracy is not increasing?
I am solving a classification problem using the pre-trained modelwhich is trained on similar dataset i made last few layers as trainable layers. My data is around 40k and nearly 8M trainable parameters are there after fine-tuning the model. In spite of using a pre-trained model, I am getting weird results.
No matter how many epochs I use or change the batch size and learning rate, my validation accuracy is not increasing, but my validation loss is decreasing continuously.[
My validation loss is less than training loss throughout the training. To handle this, I ensured there was no data leakage from the training set to the validation set. But still, in the pre-trained model, there are some regularizations like dropout, so validation loss can go down.

How is this possible? It seems that if validation loss decreases, accuracy should increase.
I researched my problem and found out that it is happening because of the label mismatch I am using CrossEntropyLoss, and my labels started from 1, so  I corrected the label starting from 0 but still got similar results. I also changed the train-test split, but no improvement.
Here, validation loss is decreasing along with training loss, so this will not result in overfitting.
It would be a great help if anyone could explain why this is happening and how I can improve the validation accuracy.
